# Specialization of a class template with the given class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a class A and a class template B declared as follows:

```
class A;

template <class T>
class B;
```

I want to declare a specialization of B for T=int, which coincides with A, i.e. something like this

```
template<>
class B<int> = A;
```

Comment: Not possible; you can have `B<int>` publicly derive from `A` though.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you for the comment, it is a nice solution, but I prefer the one without using inheritance (See the answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate such behavior of `B` via nested classes and C++11 template aliases:

```
class A;

template <class T>
struct B_
{
    class type{ /* Implement your general version of B here */ };
};

template <>
struct B_<int>
{
    using type = A;
};

template <class T>
using B = typename B_<T>::type;
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f950923904e74b1f)

Comment: The downside is that `T` will be in a non-deduced context when you use `B<T>` as a parameter to a function template.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, there is a disadvantage of such approach.